# SharePoint Custom Validation with ValidationFormula

Tags: 2010, validation

I was wondering if there was a way to execute a validation using the SPField.ValidationFormula before you use

```
SPListItem.Update();
```

I would like to know that a field is not valid before I execute an update command.

I can get the other validation errors (like required validation) through

```
this.Validators
```

but any SPListDataValidationException exceptions show up only after the SPListItem.Update() has been executed.

```
try
{
    item.Update();
}
catch (SPListDataValidationException ex)
{
    //Do Something            
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.